# SocialEngine staticBaseUrl is not working in production mode

Tags: plesk, socialengine

I am using socialengine as content management system, when i change the socialengine site to production mode it did not load the css file, I figured out that my $staticBaseUrl function is not returning the website name.
I manually added the path in default layout to load the css file, it works but a font family (centurygothic) is not loads. I am using SocialEngine's 4.2.4 version, please help.
I am using plesk panel for as hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use paths in your css file (theme_name/main.css or Modulename/externals/styles/main.css), you can use following way of indicating path:
`~/application/...`, where `~` will be automatically parsed and replaced by staticbaseurl.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly no need to manually adjust the `$staticBaseUrl` in the layout. There is a setting in the admin panel (general settings) where you just specify what the URL is. This is commonly used to set the CDN URL.

Secondly, most of the CSS files in production get minimized and appended to each other, so you will only see one query similar to this: `/application/css.php?request=application/themes/default/theme.css`

Thirdly, if there is still an issue there may be a number of reasons.  For example, are you using the http://example.com/home or http://example.com/index.php/home URL format?